# Calculate sum using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm building a WPF application and my model is like this :

```
public class Employee
{
        public int Matricule { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public double Salaire { get; set; }

        public Employee() { }
}

public class Ouvrier : Employee
{
        public Ouvrier() { }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
        public List<Ouvrier> Ouvriers { get; set; }

        public Manager()
        {
        }
}
```

So the salary of the manager is [his salary+bonus (2% of the sum of his workers salary)]. How can I calculate his salary using Entity Framework? And should I do the calculation in the `Manager` constructor or in ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can call `Sum` method on the Outviers Salary property and add that to the manager salaray.

```
var mgrWithBonus =  dbContext.Managers.Select(s => new Manager 
                           {    
                              Nom = s.Nom,
                              Salaire = s.Salaire +
               (s.Ouvriers!=null? s.Ouvriers.Select(f => f.Salaire).Sum()*0.02:0)
                           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Linq statement to get final salary for all managers.I susppose that managers is DbSet provided by DbContext:

```
     var managersWithFilnalSalary = managers.Select(m => 
new {m.Nom, FinalSalary = m.Salaire + (m.Ouvriers.Sum(o => o.Salaire)*0.02)});
```